# UISplitViewController maintain detail first responder for keyboard shortcuts

Tags: ios, uikit, keyboard-shortcuts, first-responder

I'm working on adding support for keyboard shortcuts into my iOS app. It is made of a `UISplitViewController`, and the shortcuts are provided by its detail view controller. The master is composed of a view controller with a `UITableView` and `UISearchBar` as table view header (using a `UISearchController`).

While it works great when I do `showDetailViewController`, I realized that in many scenarios, the detail view controller loses first responder, and thus shortcuts no longer work.

Examples where first responder is lost:

- After a search (`UISearchBar` momentarily took first responder)
- After opening a second app in multitasking (split view) and closing it

My problem seems to that be the detail view controller loses first responder and doesn't get it back.

Reading the documentation I've seen that I could override `nextResponder` in all responders so that they designate the detail view controller. But this seems overkill as there are many of these potential responders...

What do you think is the best approach / practice to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you find a solution  to this?

Answer (score 1):

First you should make sure in your `DetailViewController` you return `true` from `canBecomeFirstResponder` and call `becomeFirstResponder` in `viewDidAppear`. This is covered in [WWDC 2020 Support hardware keyboards in your app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10109/). This will fix the problem that the detail controller is not becoming the responder when a selection is made after editing the search field.

Then you could improve on this by calling `detailViewController.becomeFirstResponder()` when the search bar text field ends editing.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder

For after multitasking you could perhaps listen for `UIViewControllerShowDetailTargetDidChangeNotification` and do the same.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollershowdetailtargetdidchangenotification